# Debian 10 freeze after wake up with message "BIOS contains WGDS but no WRDS"

Tags: debian, freeze, bios, iwlwifi

I recently changed my laptop to an XMG Core 15. I installed Debian 10 and updates it from main, contrib and non-free and everything is working (mostly) fine.

Sometimes when trying to wake up the laptop, the screen freeze after the password just before displaying the Desktop. I have no access to other tty and no other choice than to restart it. Sometimes I will find my laptop super hot when pulling it out of my bag with a black screen and one or two lines saying BIOS contains WGDS but no WRDS (which also appears at every boot). Again, no other choice than to restart it.

I don't know if those two issues are related but it happens too often to be acceptable and I would like to figure out where this error comes from.

By the way, everything is working fine when the pc boot normally, no wifi issue, no performance issue.

**What I tried:**

I understood that this error message has to do with `iwlwifi` but my wifi connection works fine so it is a bit hard to diagnostic.

I search for a kernel update for my system. I currently have 4.19.0-6-amd64 which is not the newest version but I don't think there is a more recent one available for Debian 10.

**My config:**

Debian: `Linux taniere 4.19.0-6-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.67-2+deb10u2 (2019-11-11) x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Hardware (output of `lshw -short` command):

```
H/W path           Device     Class          Description
========================================================
                              system         XMG CORE (M19, GTX 1650) (XCO15M19_XCO17M19)
/0                            bus            XMG_GK5CP5V_GK7CP5R_M19
/0/0                          memory         64KiB BIOS
/0/3a                         memory         16GiB System Memory
/0/3a/0                       memory         16GiB SODIMM DDR4 Synchronous 2667 MHz (0.4 ns)
/0/3a/1                       memory         [empty]
/0/3a/2                       memory         [empty]
/0/3a/3                       memory         [empty]
/0/46                         memory         384KiB L1 cache
/0/47                         memory         1536KiB L2 cache
/0/48                         memory         12MiB L3 cache
/0/49                         processor      Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-9750H CPU @ 2.60GHz
/0/100                        bridge         Intel Corporation
/0/100/1                      bridge         Skylake PCIe Controller (x16)
/0/100/1/0                    display        NVIDIA Corporation
/0/100/1/0.1                  multimedia     NVIDIA Corporation
/0/100/2                      display        Intel Corporation
/0/100/12                     generic        Intel Corporation
/0/100/14                     bus            Intel Corporation
/0/100/14/0        usb1       bus            xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/14/0/2                 generic        USB2.0-CRW
/0/100/14/0/6                 input          ITE Device(8291)
/0/100/14/0/d                 multimedia     HD Webcam
/0/100/14/0/e                 communication  Bluetooth wireless interface
/0/100/14/1        usb2       bus            xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/14.2                   memory         RAM memory
/0/100/14.3        wlo1       network        Intel Corporation
/0/100/15                     bus            Intel Corporation
/0/100/16                     communication  Intel Corporation
/0/100/17          scsi1      storage        Intel Corporation
/0/100/17/0.0.0    /dev/sda   disk           250GB Samsung SSD 860
/0/100/17/0.0.0/1  /dev/sda1  volume         511MiB Windows FAT volume
/0/100/17/0.0.0/2  /dev/sda2  volume         244MiB EFI partition
/0/100/17/0.0.0/3  /dev/sda3  volume         232GiB LVM Physical Volume
/0/100/17/0.0.0/4  /dev/sda4  volume         15MiB reserved partition
/0/100/17/0.0.0/5  /dev/sda5  volume         92GiB Windows NTFS volume
/0/100/1b                     bridge         Intel Corporation
/0/100/1d                     bridge         Intel Corporation
/0/100/1d/0        enp3s0     network        RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
/0/100/1e                     communication  Intel Corporation
/0/100/1f                     bridge         Intel Corporation
/0/100/1f.3                   multimedia     Intel Corporation
/0/100/1f.4                   bus            Intel Corporation
/0/100/1f.5                   bus            Intel Corporation
/0/1                          system         PnP device PNP0c02
/0/2                          input          PnP device PNP0303
/0/3                          system         PnP device PNP0c02
/0/4                          generic        PnP device INT3f0d
/0/5                          system         PnP device PNP0c02
/0/6                          system         PnP device PNP0c02
/0/7                          system         PnP device PNP0c02
/0/8                          system         PnP device PNP0c02
/1                            power          To Be Filled By O.E.M.
```